# Implementing read/write characteristic in the CoreBluetooth.framework

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am working on the corebluetooth framework currently I have created the peripheral with the writable and readable characteristic . Its working fine for me . But I want to create read- write peripheral .I have tried following :

```
characteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:characteristicUUID
                                                                  properties:(CBCharacteristicPropertyRead|CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite)
                                                                       value:nil
                                                                 permissions:(CBAttributePermissionsWriteable|CBAttributePermissionsReadable)];
```

but its not working in above case also the property is either readable or writable not both at a time .I think it is taking the first one . am I missing anything ?

Comment: try like this `(CBCharacteristicPropertyRead & CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite)`

Comment: @Tony:No its not working

Comment: Erik: AND'ing those to constants results in '0'.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that you should check:

1. Make sure that when you use the method `- (void)writeValue:(NSData *)data forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic type:(CBCharacteristicWriteType)type`, the CBCharacteristicWriteType you use should match the CBCharacteristic properties.
2. In your peripheral implementation,

`- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests`,

make sure you don't have this gem in there: `

`[peripheral respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorWriteNotPermitted];`

I copied that from the CoreBluetooth Programming Guide, and it messed me up for a full hour.